# Dock and "When switching to an application, switch to a Space with open windows for that application"

Tags: macos, applications, dock, spaces

With `System Preferences: Desktop & Dock: Mission Control`: "`When switching to an application, switch to a Space with open windows for that application`" disabled, transitions to other spaces still occur.

When I click an app icon in the dock
for an app which does **not** have
an associated window open in the present space,
I'd like to stop switching to
a a window associated with the app which
is open in a different space.

Instead, I'd like clicking the dock app icon to
activate the app (in the top/menu bar) if it is not active and to
open a new window or do nothing if it is the active app.

If multiple associated windows were open in the current space,
I'd like to cycle through them and only them on the current space,
so long as
"When switching to an application,
switch to a Space with open windows for that application"
is enabled.

[Written while using macOS 13.2.1 (Ventura) - presently latest stable.]

Comment: That setting (or lack of it) does not prevent an application from switching spaces itself when you focus an application.  Slack is an example of an app that will switch to the active space, regardless of the option.